# Continuity of piecewise functions with $g(x) = f(x_0)$ and $g(x) = f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Define function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=f(x_0)$ when $x \leqslant x_0$ and $g(x) = f(x)$ when $x > x_0.$
>
> Show that $g$ is continuous.

So essentially we have

$$g(x)= \begin{cases} 
      f(x_0) & x\leqslant x_0 \\
      f(x) & x >  x_0 
   \end{cases}$$

right?

Then $$\lim_{x\to x_0^-}g(x)= \lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x_0)= f(x_0) =g(x_0)$$

and this would satisfy the left-sided limit.

From the right-sided limt I don't quite get the same result.

$$\lim_{x\to x_0^+}g(x)= \lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x)= f(x_0) =g(x)$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in the end, $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$

Answer (score 1):

Your last line reads

$$\lim_{x\to x_0^+}g(x)= \lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x)= f(x_0) =g(x)$$

but it should be

$$\lim_{x\to x_0^+}g(x)= \lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)= f(x_0) =g(x_0).$$

This only discusses continuity at $x_0$. You also need to comment on continuity at other $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Your last equality should be $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ and that would finish the proof.

Comment: But we defined $g(x) = f(x)$, when $x > x_0$?

Comment: What is $g(x_0)$? It is equal to $f(x_0)$ by definition, right?